# SolrCloud swap cores or create new collection/alias

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

If you need to reindex without affecting queries, is it better to have two cores and swap, or create a new collection, index, create an alias, and delete the collection previously associated with the alias?

What are the trade offs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr handles the index swap automatically so no manual steps are required.

If you index very large indexes you could index on one core and replicate the result to the slave cores for added throughput.

When we indexed our large index we swapped our core into the replication domain but that shouldn't be needed if you don't want to, as in our case, want to verify the data before release.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. We currently have a primary and reindex core in non-cloud setup. Populate reindex, then swap; works great. Moving to cloud setup. Populating reindex, it replicates the data across the reindex cores in the slaves, but the core swap does not replicate. Swapping via SolrJ CoreAdminRequest.

Comment: The master is actually queried by the slaves for update, maybe the interval is wrong or you might need to fire the sync manually sometimes. Lastly does the slaves have access to the masters web front?

Comment: I didn't mention that the master is primary where you reindex and swap. And as long as the slaves can query that server for hash changes it should see the change when swapped. Might take a while.

Comment: Ah! I think you are using the old style replication. I should have been clear that I'm using SolrCloud push style replication.

Comment: Well I can't see that this feature has changed though. Seems just that instead of having many slaves replicating the data one could do that function and the index will then be replicated in the cloud. Then again haven't used this feature so take this comment with a grain of salt. Good luck

Comment: Another way that seems feasible is to take a node out of the cloud, index it and reintroduce it to the cloud. This should trigger a resync imho.